# How to return a Lambda Function through a Custom Function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I know there are alternatives to this. You can simply pass the variables you want to pass to the custom function. But that's not what I want to happen. Something like:

```
=CUSTOMFUNCTION(A2,A3)(A4,A5)
```

Dynamically generating functions from a set of parameters. I can see this being useful in *some* places, but it definitely is niche.

I've tried passing the following:

```
return LAMBDA(var1, var1 + 1) // returns a "Undefined function" Error.

return "LAMBDA(var1, var1 + 1)" // returns a string. I tried appending a (A4) in Google Sheets, doesn't work.

return (var1) => var1 + 1 // returns a string, surprisingly.
```

I'm at least 90% certain that what I'm thinking of here is currently unsupported. But it would still be great if I can get an answer.

Comment: I do not think that is possible with a custom function because you cannot use `Range.setFormula()` in that context. Make sure you are not asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Comment: "LAMBDA(var1, var1 + 1)". Leaving aside the fact that native functions can't be called in apps script, may I respectfully suggest that the syntax of your `LAMBDA` function is invalid on two counts. First, the variable ("var1") ends in a digit and (based on my limited testing) this seems to be a no-no - "var" is OK, "var1q" is OK, but "var1" will result in an error. Second, you need to include the cell reference containing the value of the variable. So, a valid function might be `=lambda(var,var+1)(A2)`, where cell A2 contains the value of "var".

Comment: Have you considered writing a script that uses `setFormula(formula)` [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's suggestions! I should have made it clear that this was mostly a hypothetical and the way I wanted it to work won't. I wanted that specific syntax, but I'll have to go a different route then. I'll take both your suggestions and just use `setFormula()` on a different cell. Also, good point @Tedinoz about the variable names, should have just stuck with foo and bar.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done, because Google Sheets [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) can only return numbers, text strings, Booleans, Date objects, and arrays that contain those types of values. They cannot return lambda functions or formulas, and cannot use `Range.setFormula()` or other such methods.

What you *can* do, however, is to return lambda functions within `let()`. Named lambdas are [first-class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) so they let you implement [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), true [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) and other types of abstractions. They make the Google Sheets formula language [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) even if you do not use [named functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534).

See [How to implement recursion in a Google Sheets formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75789097/13045193) at Stack Overflow for some examples.